# Parse Cloud code "first" query array returns different results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, parse-platform, promise

I have a simple query as follows :

```
var getGreaterQuestion = function (gid) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Question"));
    query.equalTo("groupId", gid);
    return query.first();
}
```

I am preparing an array consisting of this function :

```
var groupIds = _.range(1, 17);
var groupIdAndRandomNumberPack = _.map(groupIds, function (gid) {
   return {groupId: gid, random: Math.random()};
});

var pack = _.map(groupIdAndRandomNumberPack, function (queryItem) {
   return getGreaterQuestion(queryItem.groupId, queryItem.random);
});
```

In `pack` array, there are 16 different "first" queries for `Question` class.

I am running this query using following code snippet :

```
return Parse.Promise.when(pack).then(function () {
        console.log("arguments : " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
...
...
);
```

arguments is the result of my query retrieving data from MongoDB.

If I run this query on parse backend, arguments json format is shown as below :

```
{
   "0":{QuestionObject},
   "1":{QuestionObject},
   ...
   "16":{QuestionObject}
}
```

If I run this query on my local parse instance with MongoDB defined on MongoLAB, it gives the following result :

```
{
   "0":[
      {QuestionObject},
      {QuestionObject},
      ....
      {QuestionObject}
   ]
}
```

What is the reason of this difference? Is there any configuration I need to apply on MongoDB or parse express application for getting the same result as parse backend gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue with `Parse.Promise.when` function. Its implementation seems changed with [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/commit/7da2856b18ca1672766612700139757300ecbf62) commit.

Back then `when` function was applying all results to your callback function regardless of how you supply inputs to `when`. These calls result to same output:

```
Parse.Promise.when([promise0, promise1, ...]).then(resultFunc)
Parse.Promise.when(promise0, promise1, ...).then(resultFunc)

var resultFunc = function() {
    console.log("arguments : " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
    //prints out like {"0": promiseResult0, "1", promiseResult1, ...}
}
```

Now, this behaviour is changed. It will return as one array if you supply input promises as array, it will apply as arguments if you do so. See [this line in commit](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/commit/7da2856b18ca1672766612700139757300ecbf62#diff-d039db261f6dfd5a6ec848b532d4a6aaR394).

Comment: Ouch, an "adaptive when()" falls somewhere between magnificent and confusing. Will take some getting used to.